# Laravel - how to disable web middleware group for some routes in web.php without editing kernel or any other files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I amm working on a laravel 8 project that encoded with source guardian
and only file i can edit is routes/web.php and cant edit api.php

so how can i add routes to api group using web.php and disable web middleware group for them?
i cant edit any file but web.php

Comment: You can remove current api.php and create a new api.php if you know all routes and controllers name and other necessary data.

Comment: @MartinAmu ... they can only edit the web.php file

Comment: @lagbox I understand but from web.php they probably could not affect on api.php. api.php is encrypted but they could delete or rename it and create a new one if they have related data.

Comment: @MartinAmu they are not trying to edit routes, they want to add new routes and they can only edit the web.php file

Comment: @lagbox "add routes to api group using web.php and disable web middleware group for them". you answered the second part of their question. I mean if they want add new api routes then the only way is the add new routes and old routes together to a new api.php if they know old routes which have been encrypted.

Comment: @MartinAmu no that is not the only way, that is completely incorrect .... the api.php file just has a route group applied with a middleware and prefix, that is all, there is literally nothing special about web.php or api.php, its the service provider that wraps it in a group not the files themselves ... you could have a single route file with all your routes and groups in it if you wanted to (like how it was done for years)  ... every single route gets registered individually there is no concept of what file they come from

Comment: @MartinAmu np, check `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider@boot` to see how those files are loaded  .... though the real question is why is only the `web.php` file able to be edited and not also the `api.php` file; that is an interesting thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `withoutMiddleware` method to exclude middleware from routes:

```
Route::withoutMiddleware('web')->group(function () {
    // your routes without the 'web' middleware assigned
});
```

To mimic the group that the `api.php` file is loaded into you would have to add the 'api' middleware and a prefix:

```
Route::withoutMiddleware('web')->middleware('api')->prefix('api')->group(function () {
    ...
});
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Middleware - Registering Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#excluding-middleware) - `withoutMiddleware`

Comment: Thank you sir i think this should work, I'll test that as soon as i can

Comment: Hello, i test that and route did not have function named withoutMiddleware and then i realized the laravel version is 6